# C# Generics: How to use nameof to get the name of a base class property

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, nameof

I have an inheritance hierarchy like the following:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public string MyProperty {get; set;}
}

public class B : A
{
    
}

public class C : A
{
   
}
```

I then have a method that uses generics:

```
public void MyMethod<T>() where T : A
{
    var str = nameof(T.MyProperty); // this one fails
}
```

I'm trying to get the name of `MyProperty`, but it fails because I'm trying to do this through a type instead of an object. Is there a clever way of getting the property name without having to pass an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nameof(A.MyProperty)`.

You constraint `T` to be an `A` anyway.

Comment: Awesome. Not sure why I wasn't thinking that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option wold be to create "dummy" instance of `T`:

```
public void MyMethod<T>() where T : A
{
    var t = default(T);
    var str = nameof(t.MyProperty);
}
```

It seems that compiler is [smart enough](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDClpA3oaY+WQIbADOALlC2J+VlIBBQvQIBIEuRwAGUgFkAngAUoEAA4wonRXVIBzGJwDcpdkdMBfQtYKEpFAEKkQw0YRseiZCjVciCMU87b3IUBUV5IwALCAATAB4AFQA+AAoASlIAd2itGFIklzdAwnEANxYoUn4AXlI4mAAzFgBXABtONKSM4zLK6q5q+oA7FgBbGAgmtM4AOiVVDS0dXoYmSggR9gh2mDmAdSgAS04YNKG1gltLIA===) to remove this dummy instance in release configuration.